# ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver with Wildfly 10.0.0.Final

Tags: java, mysql, datasource, wildfly, classcastexception

I'm taking `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource` when trying to use the Wildfly 10 datasource.

This is my datasource configuration in standalone-full.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/casadocodigoDS" pool-name="casadocodigoDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/casadocodigo_javaee</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

And my driver configuration:

```
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
    <datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

I put the jar in the folder: `modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main`. With module.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Any ideias? I'm using Wildfly 10.0.0.Final. **When I put exactly the same configuration in Wildfly 9.0.2.Final everything works fine**.

Here is the full Stacktrace:

```
21:22:47,850 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."casadocodigo.war#casadocodigo-dev": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."casadocodigo.war#casadocodigo-dev": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: casadocodigo-dev] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: casadocodigo-dev] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to open JDBC connection for schema management target
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.prepare(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/casadocodigoDS
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.prepare(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:38)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/casadocodigoDS
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:656)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:429)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:747)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:350)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:285)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1319)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:626)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:598)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:590)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031089: Failed to load datasource: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:650)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:311)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:633)
    ... 30 more
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**datasource-class** is supposed to be a java.sql.DataSource implementation.
You should use driver-class in your driver definition or use :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource
```

Be careful, in this case you have to use connection-properties instead of connection-url in your datasource definition.
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6198

Comment: Thanks @ehsavoie. Only for log and other doubt. The connection property that is needed is: `<connection-property name="DatabaseName">DBName</connection-property>`.

Comment: According to MySQL driver https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html you can use the properties : Url, DatabaseName, Port, ServerName, etc. I guess that localhost 3306 are default values thus in your case DatabaseName is the only one needed

Comment: Thats true @ehsavoie. But I search and can't find why we still need `<connection-url>` tag. And if I set `<connection-url />` or completely remove it, I take an error: `failure description: "WFLYCTL0155: connection-url may not be null`
So, I need to keep *connection-url* but all configuration I have to set a new `connection-property` tag. Thats right?

Comment: Yes that's because it is declared as mandatory in the management model. You may watch https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6200 The issue is we may not not have the driver configuration when validating the datasource configuration before trying to apply it.

Comment: Please note that if you are using the newer MySQL artifacts (8+) then this class's package name has changed to: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource`. I had to dig into the compiled mysql-connector-java jar to find that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below configuration in the spring boot application using YAML configuration in `application.yml`.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
    username: root
    password: root
```

It is working well in latest spring boot 2.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error but for a different application called webMethods Designer. I changed the DataSource class to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` as indicated above and it worked fine. Thanks for sharing.